# Can I use The Existing Crystal Report file(.Rpt) from VB and use it in ASP.Net Directly

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I am Rewriting Code from VB(Windows Applicaiton) to ASP.NEt(Web application).

And I have found that they are using one rpt file (ORDRPRNT.RPT) in VB 6.0 . I have added crystal report viewer in one aspx page of my new ASP.Net website and configured the report source to the same rpt file(ORDRPRNT.RPT) which used in VB code.

On clicking on Edit Report, I have configured the same Datasource name  in RPT file. On further I got below message, even though the database is having the table (ref_print_head)

### Remove Table

### The database table "ref_print_head" cannot be found. Proceed to remove this table from the report?

### Yes   No

Some one please let me know ,Can I straight away used the existng rpt file in ASP.net ,which has been used few years back in VB code OR  I need to make any settings in ASP.Net?
.